# search content using texbox when enter button is pressed

Tags: c#, asp.net, using

I am using two text boxes for search the content.

In one textbox topic name and another one is filename.

If I entered the topic name in textbox and press enter button in keyborad means it ill go to the topic list.

Comment: paste Some Code What Your Tried...??

Comment: what is this tag `using` means?

Comment: What you want actually ?

Comment: what i want is when the enter key is pressed the content in textbox should go the location

Comment: where you going to search...in flolders? or db?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is what you need but i think what you are asking is when you hit enter button in a textbox you want to invoke a method that searches your database. If i am true than you need to use TextBox events.

I personally use KeyDown event for this. You can invoke the event by going Events section in properties window(the lightning symbol) [check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNBcn.png) double click the KeyDown event or if you can't it find there you can go to your form_load method and do this

```
textBox1.KeyDown +=
```

after here press TAB key twice and visual studio will create your event method.

In that method you can use this :

```
        private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
            {
             // do your search
             e.SuppressKeyPress = true; // to avoid annoying BING ! sound.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist add this namespace : `using System.Data.SqlClient;`

You can use these following codes for searching from database and show the result in the textbox.

```
private void SearchText_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter || e.KeyCode == Keys.Return)
        {
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection("Your String Connection");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select Name, FileName From Table Where Name Like @Name", sql); //For Name
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", string.Format("%{0}%", textBox1.Text));
            SqlDataAdapter adapter_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(@"Select Name, FileName From Table Where FileName Like @FileName", sql); //For FileName
            adapter_1.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", string.Format("%{0}%", textBox2.Text));    
        }
    }
```